# Raspberry Pi, pyserial not working with arduino

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, archlinux

I have the following python script being called with `sudo python test.py get` or `sudo python test.py led` bringing up the following errors:

**Terminal output:**

```
[pi@raspberrypi pi]$ sudo python test.py led
led
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    send()
  File "test.py", line 10, in send
    ser.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 450, in read
    ready, _, _ = select.select([self.fd, self.pipe_abort_read_r], [], [], timeout)
KeyboardInterrupt
[pi@raspberrypi pi]$ sudo python test.py get
get
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    get()
  File "test.py", line 14, in get
    ser.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 450, in read
    ready, _, _ = select.select([self.fd, self.pipe_abort_read_r], [], [], timeout)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

**test.py script:**

```
#!/bin/python

import sys
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

def send():
    ser.write(bytes('led', 'ascii'))
    return ser.readline()

def get():
    ser.write(bytes('get', 'ascii'))
    return ser.readline()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if str(sys.argv[1]) == 'led':
        print('led')
        send()
    elif str(sys.argv[1]) == 'get':
        print('get')
        get()
```

But when I run it through python directly like so:

```
sudo python
```

**python console:**

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
>>> def send():
...     ser.write(bytes('led', 'ascii'))
...     return ser.readline()
... 
>>> def get():
...     ser.write(bytes('get', 'ascii'))
...     return ser.readline()
... 
>>> print(send())
b'LED on\r\n'
>>> print(get())
b'1023\r\n'
>>>
```

Running the same script directly works and I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: It seems like you are aborting the script with Ctrl+C while its stuck in the blocking function `select` in `serialposix.py`!? If so, the serial library waits for input but isn't receiving any (valid). Have you verified that you are using the correct device file in both runs? If you unplug the USB cable and plug it in again - the device may change. Can you provide the belonging Arduino code?